# How do I fix the garbled application name in the Launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, .desktop, sublime-text

So, I've got this problem:

[image]

When I installed Sublime Text 3 and opened it, I typed some random text just to play with it. Sublime Text will start to title a new file with whatever text is on the first line of the file. That was showing up in the Launcher as part of the normal program dialog

I then 'Locked to Launcher' and closed it. But I've noticed now that the program title has inherited that garbled text. I'd love to fix that.

I've already checked it's **.desktop** file and I don't see the garbled text there. Any idea where I could look next?

I've also tried removing and reinstalling the program, but that didn't seem to fix it. That said, I think all the config files stayed when I removed it so whatever this issue is also stuck around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstalling won't fix it. Removing the ***local copy*** of the `.desktop` file will :).

Look in `~/.local/share/applications`, find the offending `.desktop`file and remove it. Log out and back in and it is fixed.

#### Why reinstalling didn't fix it

Local `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications` overrule the global ones in `/usr/share/applications`. Reinstalling will reinstall everything, except local files, like personal settings and local `.desktop` files.

Comment: @JasonMehmel don't mention it, you're welcome!